# App for listening to an orchestra instrument by instrument

Tags: solos

There is a similar question on the forum, but not quite the same.
Do you know of any app able to show orchestra whole music sheet, play tutti, and allowing to select one or several instruments you would like to listen to.
This is not a question about isolating the sounds, I suppose here that there is one soundtrack by instrument (studio recording for example).

Thank you,
--Fred

Comment: Orchestras are almost never recorded one soundtrack per instrument.  Even in the studio they are recorded as one big group.

Comment: App recommendations are considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Fred, you can have some fun with this by listening to some midis with for example Anvil Studio.  The midis will be electronic so it won't be the same experience, and you'll be limited to midis that people have already made, but otherwise I think this could be useful and fun for you.